# Find out the child-type of an element of parent-type vector

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

I have a abstract parent class named "Form" and some child classes, as for example
"Circle" and "Star". 
If I save multiple instances of those child classes in a parent-type vector, is there any way I can find out the child-type of a single element?

//Classes

```
class Form {

public:
Form();
virtual ~Form() = default;
virtual  void Draw(CDC* pDC)abstract;

};

class Circle :public Form {
public:
Circle();
~Circle();

void Draw(CDC* pDC) override;
CPoint GetUpperLeft();
CPoint GetLowerRight();


private:
CPoint m_upperLeft;
CPoint m_lowerRight;
};
```

//Main

```
int main(){
std::vector<Form> m_forms;
m_forms.pushback(Circle());
m_forms.at(0);//??

}
```

Comment: One question here is why you want to know this. The whole point of virtual functions is that you shouldn't need to know, all differences between your child classes are captured by the virtual functions they have. Now there are situations where it's genuinely important to know the exact type of the child class, and if you have one of those then use `typeid`

Comment: I have to save the coordinates of the objects, so I do have to know the type to be able to access the private members. This may sound strange, I'm quite a beginner xD

Comment: Just declare a virtual function `Save` which saves the coordinates for each class. That's what I meant when I said the differences between the child classes (in this case the different ways they save their coordinates) should be in their virtual functions.

Comment: I had this idea too, but does a child need to know how to save himself?

Comment: `typeid`  works quite well, thank you dude!

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by 'need to know'. Do see a problem there? Having each class know how to save itself is a common enough approach, especially in a language like C++ which lacks *reflection*.

Comment: In the scenario you've described I'd say `typeid` is the wrong approach and virtual functions are a better way.

Comment: Hahaha okay. Well I think you have the greater experience, so I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: You have object-slicing with `std::vector<Form> m_forms;`, you probably want `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Form>> m_forms;` instead.

Comment: Yes `std::vector<Form> m_forms;` is a big no no. Neither approach is going to work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @john just suggested, you can used `typeid()`

Some thrown together code of mine which proves the principle is ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    virtual ~Derived() {}
};

struct Circle : public Base
{
    virtual ~Circle() {}
};


int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Circle c;
    Base *b1 = &d; 
    Base *b2 = &c;

    std::cout << typeid(*b1).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(*b2).name() << std::endl;


}
```

Comment: Even I don't like my answer! The question is answered but the better software solution probably involves a virtual method or two

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the ideal way but a simple one by adding a function to the parent that returns true in the parent & override it in the child so it returns false

```
class Form { 
public:
Form();
virtual ~Form() = default;
virtual  void Draw(CDC* pDC)abstract;
virtual bool isParent(){ return 1;}

};

class Circle :public Form {
public:
Circle();
~Circle();

void Draw(CDC* pDC) override;
CPoint GetUpperLeft();
CPoint GetLowerRight();
 bool isParent(){ return 0;}

private:
CPoint m_upperLeft;
CPoint m_lowerRight;
};
```

Secondly note that if you are going to create the elements while pushing to the vector you should use :

```
m_forms.emplace_back(new Circle());
```

to avoid making extra copies

Addition to this, the way you are declaring the vector of objects

```
vector<Form> m_forms;
stores values, not references. 

vector<Form*> m_forms
Or, better yet:

vector< std::shared_ptr<Form> > m_forms
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but the problem is, that I have to find out the specific type of the element. This probably isn't even possible, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well if you need the specific type i don't think it should be polymorphic.. You can jut declare someFunction as virtual in the base class & override for them all & this way you don't need to know the type